# i have multi-table .db file which i pasted in assets folder, and want to retrieve one of table's column value and populate it on spinner

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-sqlite

Below is my code, when I run this, it shows this
on **logcat**.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/com.example.dell1.policeapp/databases/AppDatabase
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1257)
     at com.example.dell1.policeapp.DatabaseHelper.insert(DatabaseHelper.java:51)
     at com.example.dell1.policeapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
```

**This is my DatabaseHelper class**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context mycontext;

    //private String DB_PATH = mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "uppolice.db"; //the extension may be .sqlite or .db
    public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private String DB_PATH = mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.mycontext = context;
        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if (dbexist) {
            //System.out.println("Database exists");
            opendatabase();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
            createdatabase();
        }

    }

    public void createdatabase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if (dbexist) {
            //System.out.println(" Database exists.");
        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copydatabase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }
    private boolean checkdatabase() {
        //SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
        boolean checkdb = false;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            File dbfile = new File(myPath);
            //checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            checkdb = dbfile.exists();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
        }

        return checkdb;
    }
    private void copydatabase() throws IOException {

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/(com.example.dell1.policeapp)/databases/(uppolice).db");

        // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myinput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myoutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myoutput.flush();
        myoutput.close();
        myinput.close();

    }

    public void opendatabase() throws SQLException {
        //Open the database
        String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null) {
            myDataBase.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
    public ArrayList < String > getTableValues() {

        ArrayList < String > my_array = new ArrayList < String > ();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + "aforce";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {


                    String f_name = cursor.getString(1);

                    my_array.add(f_name);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
            }

        }
        return my_array;
    }
}
```

**This is my MainActivity Class**

MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        try {
            databaseHelper.createdatabase();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");

        }
        databaseHelper.opendatabase();
        ArrayList < String > my_array = new ArrayList < String > ();
        my_array = databaseHelper.getTableValues();

        Spinner My_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter my_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, my_array);
        My_spinner.setAdapter(my_Adapter);


    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need the parentheses in `/data/data/(com.example.dell1.policeapp)/databases/(uppolice).db`, perhaps try `/data/data/com.example.dell1.policeapp/databases/uppolice.db`

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't work...

Comment: The error appears to be in `DataBaseHelper.insert`, which doesn't appear to be in the `Databasehelper` class you have shown. Try removing `db.close()` from the `getTable` method (perhaps code `db.close()` in MainActivity's onDestroy method).

Comment: Alternately try coding `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();` in `Databasehelper.insert`